# Amazon AWS Route 53 Hosted Zone does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

So I have moved my domain over to Amazon Route 53 and I have made a new hosted zone with all of the correct records, yet when I go to my domain, it gives me the error

`dial tcp: lookup verticeinteractive.co.uk on 8.8.4.4:53: server misbehaving`

and whenever I use a DNS lookup tool, it says it does not have any aliases. name servers or mail exchange records. It has not yet been 48 hours since I transferred it, but it has been at least 36 hours and I have cleared my DNS cache which allowed this error message to come up.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you 'move your domain over to Amazon Route 53' ?

Comment: I transferred it from GoDaddy by renaming the IPS tag to GANDI and Route 53 says they have it, so I belivev

Comment: I transferred it from GoDaddy by the way it says on the help bit

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have successfully transfered the domain to Gandi, but your domain is still [configured with GD nameservers](http://www.nominet.uk/whois/?query=verticeinteractive.co.uk#whois-results). Check this:

1. Log in to your AWS web console
2. Select Route53 service
3. Select Hosted Zones in the left pane
4. Select verticeinteractive.co.uk (but do not click on the domain name, just select the radio button)
5. Notice the 4 name servers in the right pane.
6. Next, go to domain registrar site (in your case stay in Route53), log in and configure name servers for your domain. In Route53: select 'Registered domains' in the left pane, click on your domain name, verify that in the upper right you have name servers from step 5, if they don't exactly match, click 'Add/Edit Name servers' and enter name servers from step 5)

Comment: My doamin is with Amazon Route 53 so it links to the hosted zone anyway

Comment: After you updated your domain's name servers who is and NS queries should return 4 name servers assigned to your Hosted Zone: 
http://whois.domaintools.com/verticeinteractive.co.uk
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/verticeinteractive.co.uk

Answer (score 43):

I had a **mismatch** of the `domain servers` between the `registered domain` and the `Hosted zones`.

To solve this you should copy the domain name server from `Route 53` -> `Hosted zones`:

[image]

**to:**

`Route 53` -> `Registered domains` -> `Name servers`:

[image]

However, the management console didn't show me the correct domain servers in the `Hosted zones` filed. Therefore, I had to use the `aws-cli` as follows:

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones
aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id <ID_OF_ZONE>
```

This returned the list of name servers that the hosted zone was using. Copy this list into the `Registered domains` section of `Name Servers`.

Afterwards, my A recorded started without any issues.

Comment: thanks, I was having the same issue, AWS page show me one thing but the proper name servers were listed using the cli

Comment: this answer still works on 2021-10-16. I prefer this as it's more visual

Comment: Been having trouble with this for DAYS. This solved it, thank you!

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my stuck problem, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

Just a note for those that have Route 53 domains that are not resolving, but passing the "Check Record Set".

This can be because your NS Records in your "Zone Information" and "Registered Domains" are different than what was assigned.

The name servers are assigned and can be looked at by clicking the radio button under "Hosted Zones".

Open a new window, and click on "Registered domains". Then click on your domain.  In the upper right, there is a list of Name Servers.  Those must match the ones assigned.

(Just changing the NS Records in the Hosted Zone page isn't enough.)

If there is a difference, click on the Add or Edit Name Servers under Regstered Domains.
Add them one at a time into the table.

Click modify and you should see them start working... You can check on https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: I registered my domain in one aws account and then transferred it to another. This was my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you replaced the automatically generated Hosted Zone, don't forget to go under "Registered domains", select your domain and then click on "Add or edit name servers".
It is a small link under the list of nameservers associated to your domain, if they still match the ones of your old hosted zone you should change them with the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

**foo.com** : Top level hosted zone (Registered / transfered domain)
foo.com NS records points to NS's allocated in registered domains.

**sub1.foo.com** : hosted zone
NS record points to delegated NS's (assigned by AWS)

To resolve sub1.foo.com externally create a copy of its NS record in the foo.com hosted zone.

foo.com now has two NS records:

foo.com NS record

sub1.foo.com NS record

Answer (score 0):

For posterities sake I'll give my experience.

I transferred domains from one AWS account to another and had **mismatched** name servers on the domain and hosted zones. In this case, follow the instructions above or just copy the name servers from the hosted zone onto the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential issue arises from trailing periods at the end of NS records.

In my setup, I own a domain from Porkbun and leverage Cloudflare for DNS. The goal was to incorporate a subdomain into AWS without undergoing a full domain migration. I achieved this by adding the AWS-specified NS records on Cloudflare for the subdomain. However, AWS replicated these NS records for the hosted zone, introducing a problem. The DNS records within the hosted zone had trailing periods, preventing the successful completion of the subdomain's DNS resolution.

It took me a day of searching to uncover this issue.

[image: Route 53 Hosted zone screenshot of trailing period in NS records]