# Route 53 domain not propagating

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I bought a domain through AWS Route 53 which i want to re-route to an ELB instance. I've set up the domain and DNS settings, created a record set and everything (i think).

I'm still not able to visit my URL and it's been about 4 days. When i try and visit my page i get a 404

```
Explanation: An IP address for the website you requested could not be found. As a result, it was not possible to access the site.
```

Can someone help me figure out what exactly isn't working?

The only thing i can think it might be is the name servers. Can someone guide me on how to set this up?

Edit: i've tried to redo the Name Servers and match them up in the hosted zone/registered domain area but i'm still experiencing the issue. Is someone able to help guide me through again as i must have missed a step somewhere but can't figure out where

Comment: How have you configured the `A` or `CNAME` records?

Comment: Did you setup the name servers? I don't think Route53 does that for you, even if you buy the domain there.

Comment: Share the domain and we can inspect your settings.  Typically if you buy the domain from AWS you don't need to mess with the name servers.  The fact that you are getting a 404 means your DNS records are pointing to a server somewhere. Any chance that 404 is coming from your own server?

Comment: My domain is countdownserver.com and i bought it through Route 53. The  server i want to forward to is on ELB

Comment: Take a look at these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: i have followed those steps previously too and again just now, both sets of nameservers match. One thing i've noticed is that under Hosted Zones, i have two duplicate URL records. One has the comment "HostedZone created by Route53 Registrar" and the other is empty. shall i delete the empty one?

Comment: I doubt they both have identical NS records? Anyway, keep the one whose name servers you entered in 'Registered domains'.

Comment: Still doesnt seem to be working :(

Comment: Can you open https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home?#hosted-zones: , select checkbox next to zone name and share a screenshot?

Comment: Hey, Here is a screenshot of both the 'registered domain' and 'hosted zone' http://imgur.com/a/mNK5h

Comment: It does all look good. I can see that "Record set count" is 3; two of them are default NS and SOA record, and which exactly is the third one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue, i hadn't set an alias for the domain to match to an Elastic Beanstalk instance, hence why the page was 404'ing. Do'h!

All fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Your domain has to be delegated to the Route 53 nameservers which is done via your domain registrar (whoever you registered the domain with).

Take the NS records Amazon gave you for your domain, and enter them in the nameserver delegation at your registrar.

(the nameserver delegation and setting the NS records within the zone are two separate operations, doing one doesn't automatically do the other)

Comment: I bought my domain through Route 53, i've set it up as specified online but it still does not seem to be working