# DNS wrong after migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, migration, amazon-route53, domain-name

About a month ago I migrate two domains name `mgeoffray.fr` and `mgfr.me` from OVH to AWS Route 53. Migration went right, I have new entries in my AWS hosted zones.
The problem is since 4 weeks after the migration validation when I ping my domains name I still have the old DNS IP showing.

Maybe that will be helpful in OVH I used to managed my DNS myself with bind9.
Here is an example of a configuration I used :

```
$TTL 12H
$ORIGIN mgeoffray.fr.
@          IN              SOA             nsxxxxxx. admin.mgeoffray.fr. (
           2016092002      ; Serial
           8H              ; Refresh
           30M             ; Retry
           4W              ; Expire
           8H              ; Minimum TTL
)
                     IN              NS              nsxxxxxx.
                     IN              NS              ns.kimsufi.com.
mgeoffray.fr. IN                     A               5.39.78.17
ns                   IN              A               5.39.78.17
ns1                  IN              A               5.39.78.17
ns2                  IN              A               213.186.33.199
www                  IN              A               5.39.78.17
```

I remove my Bind9 configuration then restart Bind9 to clean DNS caches.

Did I do something wrong with my Bind9 configuration ?
Is it normal that my DNS still wrong after 1 month ?

Comment: Take a look at these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/35970555#35970555

Comment: @DusanBajic Oh great that works I did not aware of that settings.... Thank you !

Comment: @DusanBajic Can you add it as an answer that I can validated it please ?

Comment: Lets not duplicate answers, the upvote to previous one is perfectly fine