# transferred my domain to AWS route53 but cannot modify it with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I recently transferred my website from my previous registrar to AWS. Following the AWS documentation, I have then created a hosted zone on AWS and a bucket on S3, uploaded my files there and changed the A name on AWS to point to it. Finally, I have modified NS, SOA and MX of my old provider to point to AWS and CNAME to point to S3 console. 
I have waited a week for the changes to take place, however, the site seems to be still hosted with the old registrar. Any change I make in the S3 console do not modify the site, while any changes I make in the file manager on my previous host provider affects immediately the site.
What should I do to transfer all my files and can manage my page on AWS?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share the domain name?

Comment: Hi Dusan, the domain name is davidebenedetti.org

Comment: Your domain name resolves to S3 bucket `www.davidebenedetti.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` but the response from AWS is "The specified bucket does not exist"

Comment: but still, your domain is misconfigured, CNAME is not allowed for the root/apex of the domain. Take a look at these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/35970555#35970555

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I followed your instruction and I believe it is pointing to the right direction now, however the server return a 403 error message now, not sure what I did wrong

Comment: Get a cup of coffee, take a deep breath, and go slowly checking step by step http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-s3-tasks

Comment: Also, it looks like you created hosted zone named `www.davidebenedetti.com` instead of 'davidebenedetti.com'?

Comment: that was so stupid on my part, I did not even notice. Thanks a lot, it works just fine now.