# Amazon Web Services Route 53 DNS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am having some issues getting Route 53 to display my website when people visit the domain name associated.

I have the domain name 'scott-t.co.uk' and have set up a Route 53 record set with 2 A records (one for www, other just for scott-t.co.uk) pointing to an EC2 instances public IP. When i try to visit either domain, both return a page stating that the website is not reachable. When i visit the IP directly, it works a treat.

The website is my personal CV website and i don't really want to be sending an IP instead of a domain name to potential employers as it looks unprofessional.

I have checked the EC2 instances security groups and can confirm that "anywhere" can access port 80 for inbound HTTP.

One thing i have noticed, is that the nameservers under the NS record in route 53 do not match the Nameservers assigned to the domain when i look in "Route 53 > Register Domains > scott-t.co.uk" but even when i copied these into the NS record, it did not work.

Also, when i go into my hosted zone and click "test record sets" both A records for scott-t.co.uk and www.scott-t.co.uk return the corresponding IP address.

I have tried several times to completely remove the record set and re-create it with no luck, and have even started everything from scratch (Terminated EC2 instance + removed record sets). I have also googled this and the majority of what i could find I have already tried. (Mainly security groups)

If i log on to the instance directly via putty and run a dig against the nameserver located in the NS record, it comes back with `Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53662
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`

I'm new to AWS, and I have no idea what else to check. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the NS record currently match the auto-provisioned name servers in `Route 53 > Register Domains > scott-t.co.uk`? NS changes take a bit to propagate.

Comment: Can you verify (from the Hosted Zone Details pane) whether your hosted zone is Public or Private?

Comment: Take a look at these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/35970555#35970555

Comment: @DusanBajic Worked an absolute treat. Spent 48 hours trying to resolve this and that just fixed it in less than 5 minutes. Feel free to submit as an answer and I will mark it as correct! Cannot thank you enough.

Comment: I am glad it help, but there is no need to duplicate the same answer, you can just upvote that one.

Answer (score 0):

When you ping your DNS records, does the response resolve to the right IP address?  Have you cleared your local DNS cache before trying again?