# Why Digging my Route 53 registered domain does not work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, dig

I have registered the domain lohce.com a year before (2016) on Route 53 and I have create a Record Set A to guide a traffic from the www.lohce.com to my EC2 instance. Everything went fine. Recently I decided to turn off the instance and create another one.

However I am facing a problem, my domain lohce.com is not accessible anymore.

1. I have successfully create Record Set A (www.lohce.com) to point to the Elastic IP of the EC2 instance.
2. I have checked that NS 4 dns addresses for the Record set A are the same as names serves in my lohce.com Route 53 dashboard

   ns-1282.awsdns-32.org

   ns-1910.awsdns-46.co.uk

   ns-855.awsdns-42.net

   ns-358.awsdns-44.com

Howerver I can dig my Record Set `www.lohce.com` as you can see here (http://www.digwebinterface.com/)

here are errors that I get from my computer

```
dig lohce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.14-Ubuntu <<>> lohce.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38347
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lohce.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 1120 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 02 06:07:59 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38


dig www.lohce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.14-Ubuntu <<>> www.lohce.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 6832
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.lohce.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 1118 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 02 06:09:05 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

Can someone can help me ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: @DusanBajic thank for your answer. This solve the problem of dig www.lohce.com from the EC2 instance, but I still get the error when I run the dig command from my computer

Comment: There should be no difference. Are you sure you din't have two `lohce.com` zones in Route53 (maybe one private, one public)?

Comment: @DusanBajic I am sure I don't have two lohce.com zone in Route53. In any case that is what my dashboard says.

Comment: If [this](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.lohce.com&type=A&showcommand=on&colorize=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) gives you correct (expected) results, then you only have some local DNS issues

Comment: @DusanBajic this give me the expected result as you mentioned. So what can I do ? do you have 35.162.63.137 as result when you run dig www.lohce.com on your side ?

Comment: Yes, I get that ip address, and Ubuntu Apache default page opens in browser. Apparently your local `dig` is using localhost 127.0.0.1 as DNS server which is somewhat unusual. Try `dig www.lohce.com @8.8.8.8`

Comment: dig www.lohce.com @8.8.8.8 worked fine. thanks however what do you get when you open www.lohce.com on yourside ?

Comment: Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Comment: on my side I got an error. I can I fix this Please, thank you for your time.

Comment: Your web site seems fine.  You have a local computer problem.