# AWS Route 53 Domain status code

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I transfered a domain to AWS Route 53 (25th Oct) and today It's 8th of November, 14 days until the transfer have passed. The actual status code is the following:

ok

I have also changed the name servers to default AWS name servers:

ns-1914.awsdns-47.co.uk
ns-224.awsdns-28.com
ns-989.awsdns-59.net
ns-1286.awsdns-32.org

But the Domain is not working. Is It currently in the transfer progress? Is It possible?

Comment: Did you transfer the domain to AWS or just transfer the DNS?  If you transferred the domain you should have gotten an email from Amazon that the transfer was successful.  Domain transfer can take 5 days depending on the "old" registrar but DNS should go pretty quick.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Domain is not working"?

Comment: Also, check these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: Sorry for the explanation. I mean, that when I create a record set, of type A for example and I route the direction to an ip, the domain is not resolving my IP

Comment: Thanks @Dusan Bajic, the domain names were different from the ones I was using, I will wait until the update of the DNSs to check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was using the wrong Name Servers in the registered Domains. Follow the answer of Dusan Baijic to solve the problem:

[Amazon AWS Route 53 Hosted Zone does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/35970555#35970555)