# Amazon Web Service - Route 53 - Configure domain and hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have moved my domain to AWS (Amazon Web Service).
In the "Registered Domains" area, 1 of my domains appears.

And in the web hosting I have my personal page.

Accessing the public IP of the accommodation, I see my website.

I need to access the URL of the domain can see the same content accessing from the IP.

How do you configure a domain to point to a hosting?

If I execute this command `dig + recurse + trace www.mydomain.com any` I get the name of the PREVIOUS domain registrer

Comment: Check if this applies to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: I have done the steps indicated by the post that you have passed me, and yes, I was missing the last step to do.

I'll wait a few hours for the DNS propagation to see if everything works correctly.

Thank you