# Domain name registered in AWS but traffic from EC2 is not being routed to the Domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have registered my domain name from AWS. I launched WordPress on the EC2 server, created an elastic IP and created a hosted zone on Route 53. I have entered the registered domain, selected A-IPv4 and entered the elastic IP I created on EC2. Logically the traffic should route to the domain name when I enter it in the address bar. But the page shows "THIS SITE CANNOT BE REACHED - (domain name)’s server IP address could not be found."

Can anyone help me with this?

Much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to get better answers for this question on the ServerFault site. https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Verify this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: can you access WordPress directly with the IP?

Comment: Yes @SudharsanSivasankaran

Comment: @DusanBajic Dude. this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You need to verify route tables of vpc. Also verify internet gateway. Verify security groups inbound and outbound traffic of EC2 instance

Comment: While potentially helpful, this isn't an answer.

Comment: What applications server are you using ? If IIS you have to add the binding there too. So, inbound and outbounds in your security group to port 80/443(https) and the binding in your IIS application.