# route53 domain name is not connecting with my ec2 elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm running an ec2 instance. If I ping the instance based on its elastic IP I get a response. If I use my registered domain I can not access that elastic IP address anymore. In Route 53 (under the DNS Management) I have 1 hosted zone with 3 record sets:

1. an A record set with my domain  and the elastic ip address
2. an automatically assigned AWS NS record
3. an automatically assigned AWS SOA record

So, basically the only entry I added was the A (that corresponds to the name of my domain  and the elastic IP address  as a value. Not sure why it's not binding.

My ec2 instance has no firewall and for the time-being both (the inbound and the outbound) sections of my aws firewall are set to "all traffic".

when I use a domain validator I do not get anything back. It behaves as if the domain did not exist. The domain was created over a year ago (so this is not a new domain). I checked in the dash-board and as far as I can tell all the information (contact info, verification info) looks fine.

Furthermore, the "test-record" feature in the Route 53 does return the IP address on a "UDP" port.

What am I missing? Do I need anything else?

**Edited**
[image]

[image]

**Edited 2**
I have deleted the 1 hosted zone and created a new: now it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/35970555#35970555)

Comment: @DusanBajic , thank you for the link. The domain has been purchased on AWS.

Comment: @Nactus, still, follow the steps (you have configured the wrong name servers, it can be seen in your pictures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bought the `Domain` from other than `AWS` then you need to manually update its `name server` from their portal (godaddy,etc).

**So this is how it goes in case of others:**

create a `Hosted Zone` in `Route53` which you already did

`NS` and `SOA` records will be auto-generated however, it's important to note that the auto-generated `NS` will **NOT** update the domain's `NS` automatically. You need to update it manually

Add `A` records as shown in image below
[image: Route54 config]

Then go to your domain portal and change `DNS`, use auto-generated DNS from `Route53`

Changes will be refreshed as per your selected `TTL` but it usually updated in 5 mins

**OR**

If your Domain provider gives you the access to setup records in their portal then you can skip all the above steps and simply create `A` record there with your `elasticIP` to point your domain to `ec2`

**EDIT**

As you can see in picture nameservers mentioned on the top right corner of the image are different than your record NS, your NS records are wrong.
It's better that you delete this hosted zone and create new Public Hosted Zone. You will get new NS after creating a Hosted Zone then just go to domain editing and update nameservers with the new one on domain.

Comment: We don't yet have enough information to know whether this is the solution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes you are right but I used to miss the point of updating DNS record on domain provider website. So I thought this might be an issue

Comment: @ UsamaAmjad, thank you for taking the time to answer. Upvoted. My domain was purchased through AWS about a year ago. The domain is in good standing with AWS - according to their dashboard.

Comment: My setup is very similar (with the exception of the "www.<domain_name>.com". I figured for a simple "ping" test from the console - the www would be irrelevant. I can ping the elastic ip but the domain does not respond. I will edit my main post and share a screen capture with the records

Comment: @Nactus Your `NS` records are wrong, as you can see in picture name servers mentioned on the top right corner of the image are different than your record NS.

Comment: @Nactus consdering your attached image your NS and SOA both records are wrong. Its better that you delete this hosted zone and create new Public Hosted Zone

Comment: @UsamaAmjad, this is the part I didn't know: so the ns servers in the "domain editing" section have to correspond to the ns servers in the "hosted-zone"?

Comment: @Nactus yes they should be same. You get new `NS` after creating a Hosted Zone then just go to domain editing and update name servers with new one on domain

Comment: @UsamaAmjad, please post this as an answer so I can choose it as the solution for this question. It turns out, after editing the NS servers on my domain (to reflect the changes in the hosted-zone) it worked.

Comment: @UsamaAmjad, answer accepted, please see my edit suggestions