# Configure SSL with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, cname

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeSe3.png) I want to configure SSL to aws and for that, I have followed below procedures:

1. Requested SSL from aws using dns method
2. they have issued me SSL with cname record
3. I have added cname record as given by them please see attached screenshot
   [image]

Still, it shows `pending validation` as it has added about 14 hours ago.what is I'm missing:

Note(domain is from crystone) and also tried to remove `_` from `cname` record value as suggested by aws that some domain name service provider not support `-` prefix.

Also removed 'aws.' (dot) that one thread here in Stack Overflow suggested.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please run a dig for the CNAME e.g. dig _x1.example.com and verify if it matches with the value provided by ACM. Unfortunately, you have blurred everything in the screenshot, so that does not help :(

Comment: hello @sudo i have added another image with clear values please check `issue image` link in question

Comment: And one more think is that required to `Certificate authority (CA) type` in aws?

Comment: dig fillerbrands.com NS +short gives name servers from crystone e.g. ns03.crystone.se. So you have to either add the CNAM record there (I believe you'll have the control panel in crystone) or do a domain delegation to Route 53. Adding the CNAM to Route53 does not have any effect since Route53 name servers are not authoritative.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: above solution @DusanBajic you suggested not working

Comment: @sudo also tried your solution to add name servers from crysone and added cname record to crystone domain control panel but no luck