# not able to point my domain name to ip address on aws

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have just started working with aws-ec2. and I have been trying to point my domain name to the ip address of an ec2 instance but it always give the error  **site can't be reached. todo.maketime.in’s server IP address could not be found.**

I created an hosted zone with the domain name maketime.in 
And then I created a recordset for creating subdomain todo.maketime.in and added the value of my ip address 13.233.138.49

on doing **nslookup maketime.in**

```
Server: 127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   maketime.in
Address: 103.209.144.177
```

and for **nslookup todo.maketime.in**

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find todo.maketime.in: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: @DusanBajic my domain name is not registered as it is paid! I am looking for something free of cost

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not registered"?

Comment: There is nothing in my registered domain.

Comment: But you (or someone else) did register the domain somewhere else (not on AWS)?

Comment: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html] I am following this link

Comment: Aarti, in order to be able to modify DNS for maketime.in domain, you need to have access to Domain Registrar control panel (where that domain name was initially registered). do you have that access?

Comment: yeah it's registered on godaddy

Comment: Then follow the steps in the above post, just in step 6. go to godaddy and enter four AWS nameservers (from step 5.) as authoritative name servers for your domain.

Comment: well thankyou. it worked :)