# AWS domain and AWS instance. Domain is coming up server IP address could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ip-address, amazon-route53

I have created a website using AWS only. My Domain I got through AWS, and my instance is running through AWS. The IP address is working fine and showing my site when I use that in any browser, as it should but the domain name I am using is not showing it, I have tried making many different host zones but I am always getting "server IP address could not be found." I have included www.tictechsolutions.ca and tictechsolutions.ca in A type with the correct IP address. I have recreated them 10 times there is no spelling error nor is the IP miss-typed, and I am using an elastic IP so it doesn't change.

[image: Route 53 configuration]

Comment: Probably a caching issue. What does https://dnschecker.org/ show?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to [cira.ca](https://cira.ca/) (the `.ca` registrar) and it shows your domain name info as:

```
DNS 1 hostname  ns-116.awsdns-14.com
DNS 2 hostname  ns-1304.awsdns-35.org
DNS 3 hostname  ns-1688.awsdns-19.co.uk
DNS 4 hostname  ns-823.awsdns-38.net
```

You will notice that these are different to the ones shown in Amazon Route 53. This is most likely the cause of the DNS lookup failure.

The DNS name servers need to match what is shown in Route 53. I'm not sure how these are mismatched, since presumably they were set when you purchased the domain.

Comment: Thanks this was the issue! I changed it on my domain and had to wait some time, but it corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes DNS propagation takes time so maybe give it at least a day for a domain to work. You can check your DNS propagation from sites like https://dnschecker.org/.