# Route53 doesnt resolve DNS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

because I was feed up by my DNS configuration of my hosted zone at AWS Route53, I decided to reconfigure it from scratch. After planning my domain incl. sub domains on paper, I created a new root zone and started configuring it. To test it, I refered to a static ip. Problem: the address cant be resolved.

When I used the internal testing of route53, everything seems to be fine.

In my understanding a aws managed domain should add the hosted zone dns entires to the domains dns entries. Is there anything missing if you deleted the initial root zone?

Comment: Try following these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196

Comment: Thank you, regarding the https://dnschecker.org/ my address is resolved proper now.
But my browser itself isnt able to resolve it yet. I asume that it will take a while till the Domain DNS change is published, or did I miss another topic?

Comment: Have you tried to run `dig <your-domain>` on your local machine? With DNS, I have also tried other approaches like checking that domain on other devices on other network (like my phone on data). DNS propagation could take some time (upto 48 hours).

Comment: Yes got it. My phone is routing proper now. Thanks both of you for the help :)