# Domain cannot resolve AWS Cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React website which I would like to host on AWS Cloudfront with custom domain.

I created s3 bucket with option for static content hosting and I created Cloudfront distribution.

I can open the Cloud distribution using the distribution domain name `d1srvdzuzxvion.cloudfront.net`

I created a hosted zone and I added DNS records

[image]

But again when I open the domain into my browser it's not working. Can you advise what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NS records you show above, do not actually match what a DNS lookup is returning:

```
NS-1337.AWSDNS-39.ORG 
NS-1871.AWSDNS-41.CO.UK 
NS-245.AWSDNS-30.COM 
NS-842.AWSDNS-41.NET
```

https://whois.domaintools.com/hireya.org

You are going to need to figure out that one first.

Comment: I need to change them with yours?

Comment: It is worth a try - that is what you dns provider is reporting as the name servers - so whatever you use, when you check the domaintools link I posted above, it should match.

Comment: I changed them but still no result

Comment: New configuration: https://ibb.co/sCtNq64

Comment: yes, this is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/58604183#58604183

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you enabled DNSSEC but did not configure it properly. Whois returns  `DNSSEC: unsigned`

This tool reports no DS records found https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/hireya.org. You either need to configure these records or disable DNSSEC.

More info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-configure-dnssec.html

Comment: This is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969976/amazon-aws-route-53-hosted-zone-does-not-work/58604183#58604183   wrong DNS