# Route53 hosted zone not seen as authoritative by Workmail even though NS records and SOA are correct

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-workmail

I am trying to add my domain (currentvoices.com) to the domain list in Workmail. I have copied the required records shown in Workmail using the copy button, and added them to the DNS record in Route53 for the public hosted zone.

I verified that the changes to the hosted domain are in sync, using the status link.

Workmail keeps saying the hosted zone is not configured correctly, that the domain needs to be set as authoritative.

I have deleted and recreated the hosted zone in Route53 multiple times, trying to resolve this issue. Unfortunately in Route53, I neglected to write down the original NS records prior to deleting and recreating the hosted domain.

Route53 creates new (different) NS records every time I recreate the hosted zone. It also creates an SOA record that points to one of the newly-created NS records.

Still the same message appears in Workmail, even if I remove and re-add the domain there.

Important: This domain has only ever been hosted on AWS Route53. Nowhere else. So it is not being managed anywhere else - that is not the problem.

I would very much appreciate any help. I'm thinking the problem may stem from not being able to update the NS records to the original ones. How can I resolve this?

Cheers,
-=Cameron

I have tried:

- Removing and recreating the public hosted domain in Route53
- Deleting and re-adding the domain to the Domains list in Workmail
- I also made sure the set of records specified by Workmail are correct to what's in the Route53 hosted domain record, in every case.

Comment: see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970555/1145196 maybe helps

Comment: It does not help. I already explained that the name servers are configured correctly, and that the domain has always only been hosted on AWS Route53. The post you suggested is for those who are moving their domain from a different hosting provider.

Hopefully someone here can answer this. Surely I can't be the only one who has experienced this problem.

I did remove and recreate the hosted zone multiple times. I also recreated the domain in Workmail. Also I made sure it shows in SES and it does, but always says pending, even though my domain has long since been verified.
-=Cameron

Comment: still, when you compare NS records for your hosted zone and nameservers configured with your domain in "Registered domains", are they the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same. That’s what was meant by my statement, “the name servers are configured correctly“.

Comment: well, it is strange. one of your name servers for example is supposed to be "ns-263.awsdns-32.com", yet is has no knowledge of "currentvoices.com". maybe check for typos.

Comment: There is no potential for typos as everything was done via copy and paste. And-- I checked and rechecked all of that anyway. It's all correct, yet the problem remains. I'm at my wits end with this. I have even deleted and recreated the domain. No help. It has to be something previously cached somewhere in SES or something like that I guess.